# Problem with mergesort algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, mergesort

this code should work like merge sort algorithm but it doesnt work and gives the output 0 instead of sorting numbers,whats the problem friends?thanks

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string[] source = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
        string[] source1 = textBox3.Text.Split(',');
        int[] nums2 = new int[8];
        int[] nums = new int[source.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(source[i]);

        }
        int[] nums1 = new int[source1.Length];
        for (int j = 0; j < source1.Length; j++)
        {
            nums1[j] = Convert.ToInt32(source1[j]);
        }
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 0;

        while (x < nums.Length && y < nums1.Length)
        {
            if (nums[x] < nums1[y])
            {
                nums2[z] = nums[x];
                x++;

            }
            else
            {
                nums2[z] = nums1[y];
                y++;
            }

            z++;
        }

        while (x > nums.Length){
            if (y <= nums1.Length)
            {
                nums2[z] = nums1[y];

                z++;
                y++;
            }
        }
        while (y > nums1.Length)
        {

            if (x <= nums.Length)
            {
                nums2[z] = nums[x];
                z++;
                x++;
            }
        }
            string merge = "";
            foreach (var n in nums2)
                merge += n.ToString() + ",";
            textBox4.Text = merge;


        }
```

Comment: One problem is that you haven't aptly named your buttons.

Comment: This is a great chance to become familiar with the debugger provided by your IDE. Single-step through the code and watch the values of the variables. Freak out when their values aren't what you expect, and make the appropriate modifications to your code.

Comment: thanks,but the name of it is correct

Comment: Aside from anything else, there is *no* reason to present this in terms of GUI code. You could very easily write a short but *complete* program (with predefined data) so we could all run *exactly* the code you're running.

Comment: 2 obvious problems: `int[] nums2 = new int[5]` will give you problems when more than 5 input values are there. And you should definitely refactor your sorting code out of the event handler.

Comment: The line `string merge = nums2[z].ToString();` will return you only one single value. Is this what you intended?

Comment: @Doc Brown:thanks,i put the value just for test and i gave elements less than 5,and about your second comment i want to get the sorted values and put them in merge,what should i do?thanks

Comment: Are textbox1 and textbox3 supposed to contain sorted comma separated values?

Comment: @ikaso:yes they seprated with comma

Comment: @arash: you missed the sorted?

Comment: @ikaso:i dont understand what you mean about sorted comma seprated but i want to mergesort the inputs that user write in textbox1 and textbox3 and also the numbers seprates the  with comma like(23,43,....)

Comment: @arash: I mean if you are expecting the user to enter his comma seperated values in a sorted order in each of the text boxes?

Comment: @ikaso:yes,the inputs in textbox1 and textbox3 should seprate with comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting your output completely, try

```
   string merge="";
   foreach(var n in nums2)
       merge+=n.ToString() + " ";
   textBox4.Text = merge;
```

(ok, this can be done faster / nicer / fancier using Linq & String.Join, or a StringBuilder, but for testing purposes this should be enough).

Perhaps this does not solve all the problems with your code above, but it will probably help you to debug it easier.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if (y > nums1.Length-1)
```

Should not be inside

```
if (x > nums1.Length-1)
```

because you want to test for each of those conditions. If you exit your first `while` loop because `x >= nums.Length - 1`, you want to ensure you've run `y` through to the end as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. the logic is a mess. you shouldn't use
   'nums2' to store result, i suggest you
   should use a better name.
2. you assign num2 = new int[5] ? you
   should use something else if you don't
   know exact length. eg use List
   instead. Slower performance but its
   more suitable for small array
   sorting.
3. int z = 0; is not a correct way to
   implement. if you have while loop and
   need increment counting, why don't you
   use for loop?
4. in 'if' after 'while' you keep
   incrementing z without reset it to
    '0' it will index out of range

The logic is much easier achievable through LINQ

```
var numA = new int[]{...};
var numB = new int[]{...};

var result = numA.Union(numB).OrderBy(num => num); // add .Distinct() if you like
```