# Problem with output of mergesort algorithm

Tags: c#, mergesort

this code gives output but it has one problem that is when user write 5,6 in textbox1 and 7,8 in textbox3 it output 5,6.i know the problem is that when the elements of an array ends,it doesnt print the rest elements of other array,i commented on line of problem.

edited:i used textbox1 and textbox3 for getting the elements of the arrays that user wants to merge

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string[] source = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
    string[] source1 = textBox3.Text.Split(',');
    int[] nums2 = new int[8];
    int[] nums = new int[source.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(source[i]);

    }
    int[] nums1 = new int[source1.Length];
    for (int j = 0; j < source1.Length; j++)
    {
        nums1[j] = Convert.ToInt32(source1[j]);
    }
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

    while (x < nums.Length && y < nums1.Length)
    {
        if (nums[x] < nums1[y])
        {
            nums2[z] = nums[x];
            x++;

        }
        else
        {
            nums2[z] = nums1[y];
            y++;
        }

        z++;
    }////----->>it works untill here

    while (x > nums.Length)///this mean when the elements of nums end,out the rest of the elements in other textbox but it doesnt do anything,whats the problem ?
    {
        if (y <= nums1.Length)
        {
            nums2[z] = nums1[y];

            z++;
            y++;
        }
    }
    while (y > nums1.Length)
    {

        if (x <= nums.Length)
        {
            nums2[z] = nums[x];
            z++;
            x++;
        }
    }
        string merge = "";
        foreach (var n in nums2)
            merge += n.ToString() + ",";
        textBox4.Text = merge;


    }
```

Comment: mergesort, textboxes, what are you talking about? There ain't no stinkin' texboxes in mergesort!

Comment: i used textbox1 and textbox3 for getting the elements of the arrays that user wants to merge

Comment: Nope, this isn't any clearer than your previous duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477248/problem-with-mergesort-algorithm-in-c

Comment: @Cody Gray:in last question i had the output 0,but now i dont have zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do (remove your last while)

```
while (x < nums.Length)
{
        nums2[z] = nums[x];
        z++;
        x++;
}

while (y < nums1.Length)
{
        nums2[z] = nums1[y];
        z++;
        y++;
}
```

because you are not aware which array items remained, also your current code doesn't work anyway, because y is not related to nums and vise verse.

**Edit:** I copy past first while into second while, fix it, remove your last while loops (2 while with if in them) and replace this.

Comment: The last while block should be using y instead of x as the index for nums1.

Comment: @arash, fixed it, @BlueMonkMN, yes I fixed it, I copy paste first while and forgot about content of second loop.

Answer (score 1):

Both your conditions on `while (x > nums.Length)` and `while (y > nums1.Length)` don't make sense, since this will never happen.

In the block before, you increment `x` and `y` as long as they are *smaller* than `nums.Length` or `nums1.Length`. Therefore those will never become larger (at most equal), thus both conditions will always be false and the "remaining" items will not be merged in.

Note that there are other things wrong in your mergesort implementation, but that's not in the scope of your specific question I guess.